# Getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when executing my Test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

Here is my code for finding WebElement for all the records in a table

```
private final static List<WebElement> listOfJobs = 
        (List<WebElement>) By.xpath("//*[@id='resultTable']//tbody/tr//a");
```

My getter method to access the private WebElement

```
public static List<WebElement> getListOfJobs() 
{
   return listOfJobs;
}
```

Here is the function I've created to collect all the records in the table in a List

```
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public static List<String> listOfJobs()
    {
        List<String> jobs = null;
        for(int i=0; i < OrangeHRMAddJobCategories.getListOfJobs().size(); i++)
        {
            jobs.add(OrangeHRMAddJobCategories.getListOfJobs().get(i).getText());
        }
        return jobs;
    }
```

Here is my test execution

```
        OrangeHRMAddJobCategories jobCategories = new OrangeHRMAddJobCategories();
        jobCategories.clickJobTab().clickJobCategoires().clickAdd().setJobCategoryName(map.get("categoryname")).saveJobCategory();
        
        Assertions.assertThat(UsefulFunctionUtils.listOfJobs().contains(map.get("categoryname")));
```

Now I'm getting an error **java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError** when I'm creating an object jobCategories. Is it an issue with my WebElement declaration? because when I wrote my code like this it executed successfully, but I do not want to do it this was, I want to user the By abstract class

```
public static List<WebElement> listOfJobs = driver.findElements(By.xpath(("//*[@id='resultTable']//tbody/tr//a")));

public static List<WebElement> getListOfJobs() 
    {
        return listOfJobs;
    }
```

Complete stacktrace

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.digicorp.testcases.TC_AddJobCategory.testAddJobCategory(TC_AddJobCategory.java:27)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath cannot be cast to class java.util.List (org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.digicorp.pageobjects.OrangeHRMAddJobCategories.<clinit>(OrangeHRMAddJobCategories.java:19)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Show us the complete stacktrace, including the *caused by* exception stacktrace.

Comment: @StephenC added above, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is in the exception stacktrace:

```
class org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath cannot be cast to class java.util.List
```

The error is in the type-cast in:

```
private final static List<WebElement> listOfJobs = 
    (List<WebElement>) By.xpath("//*[@id='resultTable']//tbody/tr//a");
```

You cannot cast a locator to a `List`.  The types are not related.

Instead, you need to call `driver.findElements` on the `By.xpath(...)` locator.  As explained here:

- [How to find element by XPath in Selenium with Example](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/find-element-by-xpath-in-selenium)

But a `driver` value probably isn't available, so that means this cannot be done at static initialization time.  That in turn means that `listOfJobs` cannot be a `static final`.

My advice ... is to avoid using `static` fields and methods for this kind of thing.

Comment: The driver.findElements solution indeed works but I wish to use the By class I mean the way I declare other WebElements 

Eg. private final By btnSave = By.id("btnSave");

Comment: Well sure.  But you can't **use** that locator without a `Driver` instance.

Comment: I think you're right, the ```Driver``` instance has to come into the picture.

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath cannot be cast to class java.util.List

You are casting `List` to a `WebElement` and it's not acceptable.

**Your code**:

```
private final static List<WebElement> listOfJobs = 
        (List<WebElement>) By.xpath("//*[@id='resultTable']//tbody/tr//a");
```

> Why do you want to cast `List` class?

We have `findElements` method to return the list of elements so you can use that.

**Updated code**:

```
private final static List<WebElement> listOfJobs = 
       driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='resultTable']//tbody/tr//a"));
```